# Is it still possible to acquire Halloween cookies in Cookie Clicker?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I've recently started playing Cookie Clicker again. Since I'm using a different computer, I've lost all my saves an had to start again.

I've started the Grandmaopocalypse event and am popping wrinklers but I'm not getting any of the Halloween cookies. I've popped 122 now- since there's supposed to be a 1/20 chance I should have got something by now, right? The odds of not getting a single one by this point are <1/1000

Am I just unlucky or has something changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Halloween cookies are only found on Halloween.
You can toggle holidays on for 24 hours once you have 5000 heavenly chips and 10,000,000,000,000 cookies baked in the current game.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now if you'll excuse me, I have a lot of clicking to catch up on.